# <a href in fireforx adds a %1B to the code but works fine with all other browsers?

Tags: html, firefox, asp-classic

Am trying to do this in classic asp.

my code looks like this.

```
<a href="Portfolios.asp?ID=<%=oRS("ID")%>">Portfolios</a>
```

when i click on this link in firefox, i find a http://xyz/%1BPortfolios.asp?ID=3 in the address bar, that results in error.

This same code works fine with IE and Chrome.

Wonder what so specific about firefox that forces this line.

I tried to use the same line but hard coded ID

```
<a href="Portfolios.asp?ID=4">Portfolios</a>
```

This works fine without the %1B added to the line.

appreciate your help.

Edit 1 (Screen Shot of Inspect Element)
[image: Screen Shot of Inspect Element]
the code on this highlighted line looks like this

```
<td><a href="Portfolios.asp?ID=<%=oRS("ID")%>"><%=oRS("ClientName")%></a></td>
```

and the resolved code is as per the screen shot

```
<td><a href="Portfolios.asp?ID=9">XYZABC</a></td>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `%1B` looks like its a url-encoded `escape` character. Often if you copy and paste code from a webpage or somewhere else, hidden characters can creep in. First thing I would try is just deleting the link and typing it in by hand (include your ASP code as well).

As you've said the hard-coded one works fine, it's looking like you're copying the link from some where else. If you type it in, you won't accidentally add any hidden characters you don't want.

Hopefully that will sort it out. I've don't it myself, so I know how easily it can happen :)

EDIT: I don't know what code editor you use, but often there is a option to turn on `show hidden characters` or something similar. In the future if you experience something like this, turn that on and you might well see a character you weren't expecting and you can just delete it.

Comment: Hello @Steve, its not copied code.  I am typing it out in every instance.  Also note, that same code works fine with IE and Chrome.

Comment: Is your `Portfolios.asp` page in the root of your website? If so, have you tried prefixing the link with `/`, so the link would be `<a href="/Portfolios.asp?ID=<%=oRS("ID")%>">Portfolios</a>`? I find it hard to believe that it's anything to do with your embedded ASP code adding something to the start of the link. Although I could be wrong, it has been known :)

Comment: Also, are you specifying your encoding in the html? So do you have something like this `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`? I might go some way to explain why you get differing results in different browsers.

Comment: Yes I do have these        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

Comment: Did you try adding the `/` to the start of the url? Have you tried the link in a Firefox on another machine? Is the site on the internet, could you share a link that I could try?

Comment: hello @Steve, no its an intranet website. its only when there is a asp script involved that i get an error. if there is no script, static html, then no error.  I have attached a screen shot, pls check

Comment: Have you tried prefixing the Url with a `/` yet? Does the character appear now? If so, is it before or after the `/`? Does your ASP set encoding that might differ from the html meta tag you are using? Also something else you could try is to build the link in a variable first, rather than outputting the `oRS('ID')` directly into the link. If you still aren't having any luck, if you want to email me outside of StackOverflow, view my profile, on there you see my website, go on there and you'll see a contact form/email address.

Comment: firstly apologies for the delayed reply.  Secondly, the site is not on the root so / option is not possible.  And putting the whole things in the variable is still no good.  problem is still the same.

Comment: That's ok, I thought you'd sorted it. Is your Firefox up to date? Have you tried it on other machines (different operating systems)? If you replace the `<%=oRS("ID")%>` with a hard-coded number, but leave the `<%=oRS("ClientName")%>` in there, does the character still get added? Have you tried hardcoding the whole page, but leaving the extension as `.asp`, so it runs through ASP, does the issue occur, gradually add everything back in one by one, but keep checking for the character, as it might be something totally unrelated, that's causing the issue.

Comment: Yes Firefox uptodate, tried this on 3 machines, did not try different OS though, hard coded works fine, but its only when a script is run, that i get the error.  No luck on this yet.  IE, Chrome, no issues.  Only Firefox has this problem.

Comment: @user3129015 try delete `="P` in `<a href="Portfolios.asp?ID=` then type again, there should be a hidden char

Comment: there is no hidden character.  its not a copied code.  written all over fresh.  i tried the page today and now i cant seem to find the error.  Firefox updated itself last week.  maybe something happened.  Thanks everyone for your effort and time.